# slide effect to entire new webpage

Tags: jquery, html, slide

I would like to create a page slider in javascript to an entire new webpage in my website. So the url needs to change. I already checked the topics on the forum about this but I would appreciate it to get some more information. Here is btw an example of what I'm trying to reach:

[link volvo example](http://www.volvocars.com/nl-be/all-cars/all-new-volvo-xc90/pages/default.aspx#)

When you go to the website and you press the more buttons you will see a slide effect to an entire new page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you inspect the code from your example and try to learn from it?